# Can interface methods be overloaded?

Tags: java, oop

I'm trying to achieve an overloaded interface method. I know that this does not work in Java, but how could I rewrite the following to have the implementation type in my `action()` methods, and not the `Base` type?

```
class Base;
class Foo extends Base;
class Bar extends Base;

interface IService {
   void action(Base base);
}

class FooService implements IService {
   void action(Foo foo) {
     //executes specific foo action
   }
}

class BarService implements IService {
   void action(Bar bar) {
     //executes specific Bar action
   }
}
```

usage:

```
Base base; //may be foo or bar
anyService.action(bar);
```

You get the idea. How could I do this?

Comment: You are violating SOLID principles?

Comment: you are doing it right. Whats the problem you are getting?

Comment: No I'm not: `anyService.action(bar)` is telling me te change the implementation of the service that is used (FooService or BarService) to `action(Base base)`. But I need the implementation instances there, and don't want to use typecasting.

Comment: Interfaces are designed to prevent such situations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define an interface that both `Foo` and `Bar` should implement, so you can do like:

```
interface Actionable{
    public void action;
}

class Base;
class Foo extends Base implements Actionable;
class Bar extends Base implements Actionable;

interface IService {
   void action(Actionable a);
}

class FooService implements IService {
   void action(Actionable a) {
    ...
   }
}

class BarService implements IService {
   void action(Actionable a) {
    ...
   }
}
```

Anyway interfaces should make your code more robust and reusable - if you are looking into hacks to make them work, consider designing your application better.

Comment: Yes this shows exactly my problem: I want to have the implementation instance of my objects in the `action()` methods. Using it as you suggested, I'd always have to make ugly typecast in each action...

Comment: Why do you say it's a hack??? It seems to be a perfectly reasonable solution for some scenarios?! (anyway +1)

Answer (score 1):

This is not supported in Java and you are violating the OOP rules.

Comment: Well could you suggest as refactoring how the same could be achieved respecting OOP rules?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your intended usage, there are multiple things to try.

If your calls to the IService know which kinds of object they can take, you could try generics.

```
interface IService<T extends Base> {
   void action(T foo)
}
```

and usage:

```
IService<Foo> fooService = ...
fooService.action(fooObject);
```

If that's not the case, you could have some check in your ´Base´ class to allow differentiation for your IService interface.

```
class Base {
   boolean acceptsFoo();
   boolean acceptsBar();
}
```

and you could use it like:

```
class AnyService implements IService {
   void action(Base base) {
     if (base.acceptsFoo()) {
        ((FooService) base).foo();
     }
}
```

**However**, this seems like a strange design. An interface is aimed at providing uniform access, and if you need to differentiate between the arguments, this is almost always a sign of an interface that can be split up into several parts...

Comment: The generic approach looks promising , BUT: I want to supply the parameter to the action() as a `Base` type, like coming from `List<Base>` that contains both `Foo`s and `Bar`s. If I just call `fooService.action(list.get(0))` I will get an error that `action(T)` should be changed to `action(Base)`, or that I must supply a `Foo` object directly. But as I do not know if the object coming from the list is a Foo object, I'd first again would have to use `instanceof` check. Vicious circle...

Answer (score -1):

You can always typecast to a specific type to execute that action.

```
void action(Base base) 
{
    if(base instanceof Foo)
    {
         Foo foo = (Foo) base;
         //executes specific foo action
    }
    else
    {
        // handle the edge case where the wrong type was sent to you
    } 
}
```

Comment: This is far from ideal - more of a hack than a solution.

Comment: The way the interface is right now, I dont see any other solution. The impl must implement "public void action(Base base)". There is no way around it. If foo / bar specific information is necessary on the impl, you will need to reconsider the interface itself.

Comment: Indeed - generics for example.

Answer (score -2):

any way if you are passing objects of sub class

then behavior (instance methods) will be called of object(subclass) passed(polymorphism)

ie.overloaded method

Comment: `instanceof` is never a solution to an OO problem. It's a quick and dirty hack to avoid implementing things in OO.

Comment: yaa you are right  . . but any way methods will be overloaded here. use instance of just to make sure